# Root systems and distinguished bases

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I'm working on Root Systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system). I learnt the basic definitions of a basis, of the Weyl group, and I read the proof of the existence of such bases for a given root system.

Now, I'd like to get deeper in the topic : I read somewhere (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0381.pdf - Corollary 5.14) that the Catalan numbers count the number of **non-decreasing distinguished bases** of the root systmem $A_n$.

This is for a school project I'm making, and my teacher told me that this was somehow linked to a group action of the braid group over the bases, or something of the sort...

Do you have any definition of a distinguished base ? Of a non-decreasing distinguished base ? By any chance, would you even have some litterature covering the link between the Catalan numbers and those bases ?

Thanks already !

Comment: Everything is covered in the paper you have linked. The first sentence says "The distinguished bases... were introduced by Gabrielov and Lazzeri in [13,25]". This means, you have to look up the papers [13], or [25], or look for another reference there.

Comment: The thing is : I did try to look for those references, but I couldn't find anything... Not even on LibGen

Comment: $[19]$ is published in the Oxford series, which should be available.